# how to pass the context.application.createDocument() to the blob to download in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, office-js

I am trying to download the context.application.createDocument()

```
var myDoc = context.application.CreateDocument("base64 format string that shows in document");
//myDoc.open();
var body = myDoc.body;
downloadDoc(body);

function downloadDoc(docBody: any){
  var blob = new Blod([docBody], type: 'application/vnd.ms-word'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a= document.createElement('a');
a.href =url;
a.download = 'myDocFile.doc';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

the result of the code is showing [Object] [Object] in doc file, it is not showing the text having some styles

Comment: please share a working snippet with the issue reproduced! if possible a stackblitz!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of downloading the base64 string of document as .docx file.

```
var docBase64 = "data:text/plain;base64,xxxxbase64xxstringxxxxxxx"
<a href={docBase64} download="myDocFile.docx">test</a>
```

If you want to dynamicly add the download link element to the html page, you could try this snippet:

```
var a= document.createElement('a');
a.href = docBase64;
a.download = 'myDocFile.docx';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```